# Python Pandas : find n in a sorted multindex dataframe and return [0:n+1] for each level 1 index

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, multi-index

I am having  some issues with what I thought a simple filtering task.
We have a data that have roughly this shape :

| name | item | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | item 1 | 0.05 |
|  | item 2 | 0.10 |
|  | item 3 | 0.31 |
| name2 | item 1 | 0.02 |
|  | item 2 | 0.07 |
| name3 | item 1 | 0.01 |
|  | item 2 | 0.07 |
|  | item 3 | 0.21 |
| name4 | item 1 | 0.03 |
|  | item 2 | 0.12 |
|  | item 3 | 0.21 |
|  | item 4 | 0.35 |

What I would like to is to return the dataframe with items smaller than 0.2 and the item directly above. This is table I would like as an output:

| name | item | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | item 1 | 0.05 |
|  | item 2 | 0.10 |
|  | item 3 | 0.31 |
| name2 | item 1 | 0.02 |
|  | item 2 | 0.07 |
| name3 | item 1 | 0.01 |
|  | item 2 | 0.07 |
|  | item 3 | 0.21 |
| name4 | item 1 | 0.03 |
|  | item 2 | 0.12 |
|  | item 3 | 0.21 |

I tried for each 'name' to find the 'item' that have a cumsum greater than 0.2 and then return the whole range with the indexes as :

```py
    df = df.loc['name1']
    idx = df.loc[df['cumsum'] > 0.2].index[0]
    iidx = df.index.get_loc(idx) + 1
    df = df.iloc[:iidx]
```

and do this for each 'name'. However this fails for name2.

Can anybody help with this please ?

Comment: I don't understand... why did name4 - item4 get dropped?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking ! I want to drop this row because item 3 is the first item bigger than 0.2. I have change a bit the description of the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR` by mask shifted per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
m = (df['cumsum'] < 0.2)
df = df[m | m.groupby(level=0).shift(fill_value=False)]
print (df)
              cumsum
name  item          
name1 item 1    0.05
      item 2    0.10
      item 3    0.31
name2 item 1    0.02
      item 2    0.07
name3 item 1    0.01
      item 2    0.07
      item 3    0.21
name4 item 1    0.03
      item 2    0.12
      item 3    0.21
```